# Difference between dir/**/* and dir/*/* in Unix glob pattern?

Tags: unix, glob

It seems that the output are the same when I `echo`ed it.

I also tested other commands such as `open`, but the results from both are the same.

Comment: @perreal incorrect, see the answer posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In traditional `sh`-style pattern matching, `*` matches zero or more characters in a component of the file name, so there is no difference between `*`, `**`, and `***`, either on its own or as part of a larger pattern.

However, there are globbing syntaxes that assign a distinct meaning to `**`. Pattern matching implemented by the Z shell, for example, expands `x/**/y` to all file names beginning with `x/` and ending in `/y` regardless of how many directories are in between, thus matching all of `x/y`, `x/subdir/y`, `x/subdir1/subdir2/y`, etc. This syntax was later [implemented by `bash`](http://brizzled.clapper.org/blog/2012/01/10/recursive-globbing-considered-cool/), although only enabled when the `globstar` configuration option is set by the user.

Comment: Thanks! I also didn't have globstar activated so this solved two problems at the same time.